# Proving a monoid is associative

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, monoid

Let M be a commutative monoid and set $M^+=$ {$a \in M : a^k$  is idempotent for some $k\ge 1$}. Prove that $M^+$ is a monoid with the binary operation induced from M.

I have proven $M^+$ is closed and that it has an identity but I am now stuck on proving it is associative. Is it enough to show that $(a*b)*c=a*(b*c)$? Or do I have to show it using the $k$'s?

Comment: I don't understand. You use twice $M$ for two different things: (a) the monoid of $2 \times 2$ matrices with real entries and (b) a commutative monoid. What is the relation between the two definitions, given that the monoid defined in (a) is not commutative?

Comment: @J.-E.Pin my mistake! I mixed up two questions sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you prove that $M^+$ has an identity and is closed under the binary operation, then you are done.

Comment: It doesn't need to be associative?

Comment: Associativity is inherited from $M$.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Right. So is the identity not also inherited?

Comment: Of course you have to prove (where $1$ is the identity of $M$) that $1 \in M^+$ (which is easy). But associativity never has to be checked for subsets if it already holds for the whole structure.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

An associative binary operation on a set induces an associative binary operation on its subsets that are closed under the operation. In your case:

$$(a *_{M^+} b)*_{M^+}c  = (a*_M b)*_M c = a*_M (b*_M c) = a *_{M^+} (b*_{M^+}c).$$